# How to run a set of select query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query

```
SELECT 'GRANT SELECT ON ' + TABLE_NAME + ' TO '+ @UserName
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND 
TABLE_NAME LIKE 'aspnet%'
```

And results like this:

```
GRANT SELECT ON aspnet_Applications TO user04
GRANT SELECT ON aspnet_Membership TO user04
GRANT SELECT ON aspnet_Paths TO user04
GRANT SELECT ON aspnet_PersonalizationAllUsers TO user04
GRANT SELECT ON aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser TO user04
GRANT SELECT ON aspnet_Profile TO user04
GRANT SELECT ON aspnet_Roles TO user04
GRANT SELECT ON aspnet_SchemaVersions TO user04
```

I want to run all of select query in this result. How can I do this?

Comment: [sp_executesql?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Sql = ''

SELECT @Sql = @Sql + 'GRANT SELECT ON ' + TABLE_NAME + ' TO '+ @UserName + '
' -- Newline to keep statements from being just one long line.
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND 
TABLE_NAME LIKE 'aspnet%'

-- Print it first to double-check that it looks right before running.
PRINT @Sql

-- After you've validated it with print, run it.
EXEC sp_executeSql @Sql
```

Comment: it doesn`t work. Error:GRANT SELECT ON aspnet_Applications TO user04GRANT SELECT ON aspnet_Membership TO user04GRANT SELECT ON aspnet_Paths TO user04GRANT SELECT ON aspnet_PersonalizationAllUsers TO user04GRANT SELECT ON aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser TO user04GRANT SELECT ON aspnet_Profile TO user04GRANT SELECT ON aspnet_Roles TO user04GRANT SELECT ON aspnet_SchemaVersions TO user04GRANT SELECT ON aspnet_Users TO user04GRANT SELECT ON aspnet_UsersInRoles TO user04GRANT SELECT ON aspnet_WebEvent_Events TO user04
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.

Comment: You didn't include the newline.

Answer (score 0):

I work it out, remember to have a space before GRANT.

```
    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Sql = ''
SELECT @Sql =@Sql + ' GRANT SELECT ON ' + TABLE_NAME + ' TO '+ @UserName +''
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND 
TABLE_NAME LIKE 'aspnet%'
PRINT @Sql
EXEC sp_executeSql @Sql
```